# Can't create IBOutlet Of UICollectionReusableView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am facing stranger issue. I have taken `UICollectionReusableView` for collection view header and set it in collectionView. Its work completely but when I create `IBOutlet` of `UILabel` in `UICollectionReusableView` It always return nil in collection view header method `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`. In `XIB` file `UILabel` is successfully connected.

Here is my code.
Register CollectionView Header

```
collectionView.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header")

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
      let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! Header
headerView.lblName.text = "Hello" //crash here
return headerView

}
```

Here its complete demo
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v2lWsQstfUiWDEldVH3Ru2HeB3LGWiXZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!

I am using `XIB` for collection view header so the way i register is for without `collection view XIB`. I have changed it

`collectionView.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header")`

To

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "Header", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header")
```